# Press conference by SC judges

Tags: india, separation-of-powers, judiciary

Is the historic press conference by four senior-most SC judges a sign of government interference in the workings of the judiciary?

References -

1. https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/supreme-court-crisis-all-not-okay-democracy-at-stake-say-four-seniormost-judges/article10028921.ece
2. https://thewire.in/law/supreme-court-judges-press-conference-one-year
3. https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/shock-sc-judges-press-conference-let-nation-decide-about-cjis-impeachment/articleshow/62471142.cms

Comment: Can you include a reference about this for further reading?

Comment: @Alexei I added the references.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to include some more information on the event you are asking about in the question rather than only references (though references are good). For example, a description of why you think (or don't think) the press conference is a sign of government interference would help answers address your concerns better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The press conference appears to have been a response to a perception of government interference in the judiciary with respect to selecting judges, and it appears that the underlying concerns that sparked the press conference remain unresolved.

On the other hand, the fact that a press conference could be held also suggests that at least parts of the judiciary believe that they currently have significant independence.